# How to conditionally import modules in PowerShell profile based on the currently running terminal?

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I want to import a few modules (posh-git, oh-my-posh, etc) only when PowerShell is launched from [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal). When PowerShell is launched using conhost or from Cmder, these imports should be excluded.

But I can see that `$profile` points to the same file when I open PowerShell from Windows Terminal or conhost or Cmder.

Is there a way I can identify the current terminal being used so I can do something like this in my `$profile` file?

```bsh
If ($TERM -eq 'WT') {
    Import-Module posh-git
    Import-Module oh-my-posh
}
```

Comment: Why not using module autoload when they're needed? You don't have to load them explicitly, you know that, right?

Comment: You could check for existence of `$env:wt_session`

Comment: Something like this should be enough: `[bool]($env:WT_Session)`

Comment: Thanks @Olaf! `$env:wt_session` is exactly what I needed.  Please consider writing it as an answer. Also I cannot autoload because these need to run on startup to change the prompt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the automatic variables `WSLENV`,`WT_PROFILE_ID` or `WT_SESSION` to check if Powershell runs in Windows Terminal. They do not exist in "*standalone*" Powershell.

For example:

```
function Test-IsWindowsTerminal { [bool]($env:WT_Session)}
```